# requestAnimationFrame trigger if element is on screen

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

For my scrolling website I want use requestAnimationFrame to create an animation.
The requestAnimationFrame must be triggered if the element is on screen by scrolling.
I have an issue with this.
The requestAnimationFrame runs only if I refresh the page and the element is on screen. If I load the page and I scroll down the requestAnimationFrame is not running.

Below my code

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    var contentPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
if(contentPosition < screenPosition){
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
                    
});
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
function run(){
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
var result = easeInOutQuart(time, from, to - from, duration);
if(time <= duration){
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    element.style.left = result+"px";
};
}

function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d){
    if((t /= d / 2) < 1){
        return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
}else{
    return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
}
}
```

I tested my code with a console.log an this works fine

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    var contentPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
if(contentPosition < screenPosition){
    //requestAnimationFrame(run);
        console.log('trigger');
}
                    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `start_time` (possibly) long before `run` is called. So when `run` is finally called, it will think it's already animating for more than the expected duration, and do nothing.

Move

```js
start_time = new Date().getTime();
```

in the

```js
if(contentPosition < screenPosition){
```

block.

However you'll face a new problem: If the user keeps scrolling during the animation, the timer will get reset and the animation will start again, with possibly many calls in parallel.
To avoid that you'd need to remove the event listener in that same block (either use [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) or an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal)).

But anyway, you'd be better using an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver) rather than listening to all the `scroll` events anyway.